# Failed to send push notification in ios

Tags: azure, apple-push-notifications

i'm using azure mobile service to send push notification.In Last month,I can send push notification.
but yesterday, sending to apns is failed with following log

```
[Error: wrong tag]  scheduler/expectationNotification
```

I've never seen this before, and a Bing/Google search comes up with nothing.

I using two azure mobile service. One is no problem,but the other is failed.

What do not people more about this issue?

Comment: Is your dev failing, but your production still working?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin, and I had a problem today. I was using a slightly old version of Pushsharp, and Apple quit allowing SSL3 on their sandbox push notification server. Is it perhaps the same issue?

Comment: I have seen the same thing after the IOS upgrade in our cordova application, may be the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You should reload your APNS certificate in the portal and the problem should go away.